# Selenium WebDriver: Unable to Select Element

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
<input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10" value="" onkeyup="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeydown="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onchange="javascript:dispLocMob(this);">
```

Shown above is the element that I'm trying to send keys. I tried by xpath and id and all sorts of selectors, but it throws an error that is shown below:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input"}
Command duration or timeout: 338 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'ClaimsCM8', ip: '192.168.110.118', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/html/body/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input}
Session ID: ec543fff-7116-4880-8c98-7c60a1c697d0
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=45.0.2}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at Selenium.Test2.main(Test2.java:62)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'ClaimsCM8', ip: '192.168.110.118', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/EFERNA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4369679942726534324webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/EFERNA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4369679942726534324webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/EFERNA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4369679942726534324webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/EFERNA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4369679942726534324webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/EFERNA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4369679942726534324webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Is there something defined in the Web Element that does not let me access the element in my Selenium script?
Any suggestions/advice will be highly appreciated.
Thanks you!

Comment: Most likely the element is not visible on the page or something else is covering it. Verify that the element is visible.

Comment: show code you tried

Comment: Make sure this is not inside any frame....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("mobile")));
el.sendKeys("your value");
```

**Note** :- Be ensure before `finding element` that it is not inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is inside any `frame` or `iframe` you need to switch that `frame` first as :- `driver.switchTo().frame("frame name or id")`

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: I tired that too, but still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you are using xpaths then use relative xpath instead of absolute as slight change in DOM makes absolute xpaths invalid or refer to a wrong element.

Second try using .click(); before .sendkeys();. So your code can be something like

```
WebElement ele = dvr.findElement(By.id("mobile"));
ele.click();
ele.sendKeys("your string");
```

Lastly, make sure you do not have any duplicate elements on the page with same property, i.e. id=="mobile". Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

1. If the element is not in any frame:

   `driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("");`
2. If the element is inside a frame:

   `// Switching to the frame`

   `driver.switchTo().frame(<framename>);`

   `driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).sendKeys("");`

   `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`

Also, please add some wait after launching the page and entering the text. And even if the code is not working, please check whether the element is visible or not using below code:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("mobile")).isDisplayed()) {
   // Add the code given above
}
```

Hope this helps